How does Devarim 28:68 jive with the opinion that positive public prophecies are never reversed?
Midrash Tanchuma (cited in Rashi to Yirmiyahu 28:7) and Rambam (hakdamah to peirush hamishnah) are of the opinion that only negative public and positive private prophecies can become undone with the betterment/deterioration of behavior respectively, but positive public prophecies can never be revoked, even if bad behavior develops.
Others argue (e.g. Abarbanel to Yirmiyahu ad loc and ibn Kaspi to Devarim 18:21) and say that even public positive prophecies can be voided with the development of bad behavior.
Devarim 28:68 reads:

וֶהֱשִׁיבְךָ יְהֹוָה מִצְרַיִם בׇּאֳנִיּוֹת בַּדֶּרֶךְ אֲשֶׁר אָמַרְתִּי לְךָ לֹא תֹסִיף עוֹד לִרְאֹתָהּ וְהִתְמַכַּרְתֶּם שָׁם לְאֹיְבֶיךָ לַעֲבָדִים וְלִשְׁפָחוֹת וְאֵין קֹנֶה.
Hashem will bring you into Egypt again with ships, by the way of which I said to you, "You shall see it no more again", and there you shall sell yourselves to your enemies for bondservants and for bondmaids, and no man shall buy you.

which refers to Shemos 14:13:

וַיֹּאמֶר מֹשֶׁה אֶל הָעָם אַל תִּירָאוּ הִתְיַצְּבוּ וּרְאוּ אֶת יְשׁוּעַת יְהֹוָה אֲשֶׁר יַעֲשֶׂה לָכֶם הַיּוֹם כִּי אֲשֶׁר רְאִיתֶם אֶת מִצְרַיִם הַיּוֹם לֹא תֹסִפוּ לִרְאֹתָם עוֹד עַד עוֹלָם.
Moshe said to the people, "Do not be afraid. Station yourselves and see Hashem's salvation that He will do for you today, for as you have seen Egypt today, you shall not see them ever again.

The Torah seems to be explicitly saying that the positive public prophecy will be reversed with the advent of deleterious behavior.
How would the first opinion account for it?
(Oddly, Abarbanel himself, to the Devarim verse, proffers a difficult suggestion in defense of the other opinion, I'm looking for something more straightforward)

The Lechem Mishne (Hil. Y'sodei HaTorah 10:4) adds a caveat to the Rambam's view, saying that a statement of Moshe Rabbeinu can be revoked as a result of sin if the statement was not explicitly made in HaShem's Name, whereas a positive public prophecy that was stated explicitly in HaShem's Name cannot be revoked.

@Fred Love it! I'll accept it should you wanna write it as an answer

@Fred I like it as well, as it fits well with "אשר אמרתי לך" ("of which I said to you"), in Devarim 28:68, being said about not seeing Egypt again, contrasted with "והשיבך ה' מצרים" at the beginning of the verse. If the promise was [a prophecy] from Hashem, it should have said "אשר אמר לך" ("of which He said to you"), or something of the like.

Perhaps the verse in Shemos is a command, not a prophecy.  Not "I promise that you will never go back there again," but "I command you not to return there again."  Alternatively, we could read it as referring to the people.  "Today you have seen these people, but you will never see them again--for they will sink to the bottom of the sea."

+1 as Chazal do indeed read the verses as proscriptions (https://yerushalmi.alhatorah.org/Sukkah/42). However, they ostensibly need to work out in the world of peshat as well (See ShM lav 46). As for your second suggestion, what then is the referent of the Devarim verse? Even if it isn't previously recorded it should still count as an abrogation.

לא תוסיפו sounds to me at least as much like a command as it does a prediction.  I think that it fits nicely as a matter of פשט.  I agree, there is a tension between the verse in Shemos, which says "You shall not see them," and sounds like it refers to the people, and the verse in Devarim, which clearly says that Hashem had informed (or commanded) them that they would not return to a particular place.

This is a case of "two verses that contradict one another, and a third comes to reconcile them". Devarim 17:16 clarifies that Shemos 14:13 must be a mitzva, explaining why it is a possibility in Devarim 28:68...

"Alternatively, we could read it as referring to the people. 'Today you have seen these people, but you will never see them again--for they will sink to the bottom of the sea.'" How would that fit with Shemot 14:30, "וירא ישראל את מצרים מת על שפת הים"?

Great question, and I'll admit I hadn't thought of it.  That said, I don't think that seeing a body is the same thing as seeing a person.  Until now, you saw the Egyptians alive and kicking.  Now, you see their broken corpses.  That's not the same thing.
